# Bootstrap slider - CSS not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, I've downloaded the Bootstrap slider: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider
I got into \bootstrap-slider-master\dist and copied the **bootstrap-slider.js** and the **bootstrap-slider.min.js** into my js folder. I also copied the **bootstrap-slider.css** and the **bootstrap-slider.min.css** into my css folder.

I now tried the example 7, check the top link and go to examples.
But there is a problem.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Test bootstrap slider </title>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
        <link href="css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <input id="ex7" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="5" data-slider-enabled="false"/>
            <input id="ex7-enabled" type="checkbox"/> Enabled
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#ex7").slider();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the result:
[My result in browser (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpxzY.png)
The text is there and the radio button, **but I cannot see the slider**. **I think the css is the problem**, but I've implemented it in the head after the bootstrap css. So I don't know why won't it work.

Comment: Please provida a mcve example.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put this wrong: `<script type="js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>`.Not type, src.
It should be:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
```

Try it now!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, you probably have referenced a wrong file or sth?
I embedded the online version of bootstrap/jquery but it should basically be the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.5.1/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">


    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.5.1/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <input id="ex7" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="5" data-slider-enabled="false"/>
        <input id="ex7-enabled" type="checkbox"/> Enabled
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#ex7").slider();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ivan's answer worked. I typed the wrong thing in the script tag, it should be script src, and I put script type. Thank you for the answer thou :)